# Null pointer exception on implementing button inside android listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Am trying to implement button inside my listview. When user click on the button in listview, it will run an asynchronous task in background. However am getting null pointer exception. please help me out.

My Custom Adapter

```
private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
            List<String> result) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, result);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
        TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
        tv.setText(code.get(position));
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_launch);
        btn.setTag(position);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new GetUrl()
                .execute("https://www.something.com/services/rest/MyAccount/"
                        + userid
                        + "/"
                        + type.get((Integer) v.getTag())
                        + "/"
                        + code.get((Integer) v.getTag()));

            }
        });

        return row;
    }

}
```

And my list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_launch"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/title"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:text="@string/launch" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:typeface="sans" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your logcat

Comment: Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_launch); change it to Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_launch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use row.findViewById() instead of just findViewById method inside the getView method

Comment: you almost reach there +1.

Comment: hmm..I was about to write the answer then i saw yours and i changes my answer to comments :)

Answer (score 2):

You can optimize and increase the performance of Listview some thing like that
[THIS](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance)

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
Button btn = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_launch);
```

The NPE here occured because you haven't given the View on which the button is placed.So If you are doing any eventListner inside custom adapter always specify the view to which you are referring

Comment: Ur welcome.But ya if it worked then mark any of the relavant answers as accpeted :)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
Button btn = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_launch);
    btn.setTag(position);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new GetUrl()
            .execute("https://www.something.com/services/rest/MyAccount/"
                    + userid
                    + "/"
                    + type.get((Integer) v.getTag())
                    + "/"
                    + code.get((Integer) v.getTag()));

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
        List<String> result) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, result);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
    TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
    tv.setText(code.get(position));
    Button btn = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_launch);
    btn.setTag(position);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new GetUrl()
            .execute("https://www.something.com/services/rest/MyAccount/"
                    + userid
                    + "/"
                    + type.get((Integer) v.getTag())
                    + "/"
                    + code.get((Integer) v.getTag()));

        }
    });

    return row;
}
```

}